# Understanding python import system and project structuring

Tags: python, python-import

Suppose I have a project organized as follows:

```
ProjectRoot/
    __init__.py
    test.py
    A/
        __init__.py
        a_test.py
    B/
        __init__.py
        b_test.py
```

And suppose that a_test depends on b_test. So the source code is relatively simple:

```
#
# a_test.py
#

from B.b_test import b_test_class

class a_test_class:
    def func(self):
        print("a_test_class")
        b_instance = b_test_class()
        b_instance.func()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a_instance = a_test_class()
    a_instance.func()

#
# b_test.py
#

class b_test_class:
    def func(self):
        print("b_test_class")

#
# test.py
#

from A.a_test import a_test_class

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a_instance = a_test_class()
    a_instance.func()
```

As long as I launch test.py script, everything works as intended. Python loads all modules without any troubles and executes them. Now the question comes: ***how do I launch a_test.py without having test.py?*** So, basically, what I want to achieve is to cd into projectRoot/A and execute a_test.py. This results in getting **ImportError: No module named 'B'**

Currently I've been able to create a project with following structure:

```
ProjectRoot/
    customLibModuleA/
        ...
    customLibModuleB/
        ...
    mainApp.py
```

And what I want to be able to create is following:

```
ProjectRoot/
    customLibModuleA/ #custom protocol implementation
        ...
    customLibModuleB/ #custom logging functions
        ...
    application1/ #server
        ...
    application2/ #client
        ...
```

How do I expected to manage complex projects? Any good references to project structuring manuals and styleguides are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my temporal solution since no one provided pythonic approach.

Folder structure looks like that:

```
ProjectRoot/
    __init__.py
    customLibModuleA/ #custom protocol implementation
        __init__.py
        ...
    customLibModuleB/ #custom logging functions
        __init__.py
        ...
    application1/ #server
        __init__.py
        __path_setup__.py
        server.py
        ...
    application2/ #client
        __init__.py
        __path_setup__.py
        client.py
        ...
```

`__path_setup__.py` content is:

```
import sys
import os

os.sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), ".."))
```

Application scripts have some setup code preceding imports (server.py):

```
#
#settings up the environment
#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    exec(open("./__path_setup__.py").read())

#
# system and libraries imports
#
import customLibModuleA.whatever
...
```

Hight quality pythonic solution to this problem is still welcome.